# Is it normal for women, or American women to use the word c*nt? Especially on public streams?

Tags: meaning, american-english, pejorative-language

There is a particular Twitch streamer from a video game I played, MermaidonTap. If you subscribed and follow her, not all but most of her public streams, she uses "fuck" and a lot of the word "cunt." I am a fellow American citizen, but was not born in US but in an Eastern Asian country, and am trying to learn English. I'm just wondering, is it normal for women to use the word "cunt" normally?

I took university English and finally passed it on the fifth time growing up in America. So I'm trying my best to understand how the words in English come about and how certain words passed down to certain generations. As I have researched, the word, "cunt" is a derogatory term towards women and as well as another meaning as vagina.

It just seems like, it's derogatory when men call women cunts. But what about women calling other people "cunts." I still find it derogatory, vulgar and I find it hard on my ears to hear words like "cunts" or "fucks" from women like her.

Also, some of my teachers and some friends and my own mother, they both say that people who curse a lot and can NOT control their word usage, means they don't know any other language but vulgar words. They didn't go through college and university. They're not educated was what I heard and been told. Do you think this is also true or not?

Overall, I'm just trying to understand the American English literacy. I don't mean to offend anyone but rather understand the meaning of the word being used at a person or in a public audience, like her on her public Twitch stream, MermaidonTap.

Comment: This isn’t the right place to ask social questions, sorry.

Comment: This is _extremely_ vulgar language. Yes, some uneducated people use language like that because it's normal in their environment, but some educated people also think it's OK to use obscene language to express strong feelings. Personally, I don't.

Comment: It's hard to give a factual answer. Some people use(d) vulgar language, from Donald Trump and Richard Nixon to Sarah Silverman or Megan Thee Stallion, some don't. It's influenced by subculture and the effect you're going for, more than education. Who are we to say who's educated and who ain't?

Comment: Define "normal". Is playing video games "normal"? Or answering questions about English, is that "normal'?

Comment: Neither I nor my wife (both US-born and raised) use "cunt", and "fuck" is used very rarely.

Comment: Not knowing who the person is, she could be a sufferer of [**Tourette syndrome**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourette_syndrome), a person who involuntarily twitches, fidgets, laughs, coughs, etc. and/or blurts out taboo words.

Comment: My guess is that the Twitch user is either British, Irish or Australian. In company of friends, these terms will be used quite frequently, often to express deep disdain and distrust e.g. "Boris (Johnson) is a c**t" but a lot depends on upbringing.

Answer (score 4):

No, it’s not usual.

It is possible small groups of close friends use this word, but it is unacceptable in a work environment, a family environment, or at social gatherings.

One guide to the socially acceptable in the United States is television (broadcast or cable) and radio between 6 a.m. and 10 p.m., the hours when the Federal Communications Commission has the authority to regulate, or fine violators. These are the hours when families including children may be watching or listening. Words such as *shit* and *fuck* are typically bleeped during these hours. *Cunt* is even less acceptable and isn’t even there to bleep—even in comedy shows.

With four continental time zones, a broadcaster must remember that a program broadcast at 10 in the Eastern time zone will be heard at 9 Central time.

The FCC is reflecting the current judgment of the public on what’s obscene, indecent, or profane, which is one way to judge what’s generally socially acceptable.  Within speech, this is can be called “register”, and is more than just a social question.

See [Bleep Censor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleep_censor#:%7E:text=The%20words%20%22cunt%22%20and%20%22,%23%40t) (Wikipedia)

Comment: I suggest adjusting the first sentence, since *normal* and *socially acceptable* are not the same. The use of pejoratives is quite common (that is, normal) in several contexts and community groups, including online gaming, even if it is not socially acceptable in FCC broadcasts, white collar offices, or in many families. In other words, socially unacceptable situations are normal.

Comment: Done.  Normal in a social context does involve a value judgment.

Answer (score 3):

Asking whether the use of such a word is 'normal' (that is, in accordance with the norms) is misguided, because the American culture (and the same is true of UK, Canadian, Australian, etc. cultures) is not monolithic (that is, it is not governed by one uniform set of norms). It consists of many subcultures, each with its own set of norms, and that includes the norms that govern the acceptability of such words.

Using such a word in a typical business negotiation, religious service, newsreporting, classroom discussion, or small talk with a person sitting next to you on a plane, would definitely not be normal. In fact that is an understatement: the use of such a word would be highly offensive, and could easily lead to one's being expelled from the relevant institution. Incidentally, as the question asks whether using the word is 'normal for women', it should be made clear that it would, in such settings, not be normal for either men or women (or for any other gender). It should also be noted that, in such settings, the use of *cunt* would be offensive not only to women, but probably to everybody present: *cunt* is the kind of dysphemism that expresses not only disrespect for what it characterises, but also disrespect for the conversational setting.

On the other hand, in some social circles within English-speaking societies, the use of such words is acceptable and not experienced as offensive. The person whose use of such words the OP has encountered probably assumes that her audience belongs to such social circles. In fact, within such social circles frequent use of such words may not only be accepted, but serve as a marker of belonging to the group; it may be a device for proudly distancing oneself from the mainstream society (which the people in question may regard as stuffy, boring, or oppressive). Understanding this social background is important to understanding why somebody would use such words frequently (and thus why it is, in a way, normal for them), even though it would be a violation of the norms that govern most other social settings.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing who the person is, she could be a sufferer of [Tourette syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourette_syndrome), a person who involuntarily twitches, fidgets, laughs, coughs, etc. and/or blurts out taboo words.

My second guess is that the gamer is either British, Irish or Australian. In company of friends, these terms will be used quite frequently, often to express deep disdain and distrust e.g. "Boris (Johnson) is a c**t" but a lot depends on upbringing and which social circles one belongs to.

If it's of help, a 54-year-old acquaintance, born and bred in the UK, often uses the term *cunt* for both men and women. This person also has a degree and a masters and is highly articulate, she's constantly reading, and as a result her range of vocabulary is extremely vast and *colourful*.

On the other hand, I have friends and cousins, (male and female) between their  late-40s and mid-60s, who went to Cambridge, Oxford, and King's College who rarely swear–it's just not in their idiolect.

Overall, the majority of British people have no problems in hearing or saying *fuck* with all their wonderful derivatives e.g.[absofuckinglutely](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/absofuckinglutely). Taboo words serve a purpose: to express an intensity of feeling such as anger, surprise, agreement, disgust or even excitement. I would not judge a person's character or intellect based on how often they swore, experience has taught me that smart bright people are less inhibited than we might imagine them to be.